# How do I prove "not (false = true)" in Lean?

Tags: math-software

As is perhaps obvious from the question, I am just starting with Lean and am missing some very basic knowledge about what features are available. Anyways, I'm trying to prove `not (false = true)` and I have this:

```
example : not (false = true) := not.intro (
    assume H: false = true,
    show false, from begin
        rw H,
        -- now I need to prove "true"
    end
)
```

The thing that's really confusing is me is that the program is telling me I have an unsolved goal, which is to prove the vacuous statement "true". I figure there's some boilerplate "cmon it's already true" statement like "qed" or "vacuous" or something but I have no idea what it is and I wasn't able to find it by skimming the documentation.

Also I'm sure this can be more succinct. But first I need it to work at all before I worry about succinct!

Comment: I do not have much experince with lean, but I have heard that there is some difference between the lattest versions lean3 and lean4. Which one do you use?

Comment: @ThomasPreu I actually do not know! I'm using the online editor at https://leanprover.github.io/live/master

Comment: The tactic `trivial` can close out a goal of `true`.

Comment: @DanielHast Ah! That's the one.

Answer (score 3):

The exact axiom that accepts true is called `true.intro`:

```
example : not (false = true) := not.intro (
    assume H: false = true,
    show false, from begin
        rw H,
        exact true.intro
    end
)
```

From https://leanprover.github.io/theorem_proving_in_lean/propositions_and_proofs.html :

> Incidentally, just as false has only an elimination rule, true has only an introduction rule, true.intro : true, sometimes abbreviated trivial : true. In other words, true is simply true, and has a canonical proof, trivial.

Other more general tactics that would have worked are `trivial` and `simp`.

From the [documentation](https://leanprover.github.io/reference/tactics.html):

> *Trivial*
>
> Tries to solve the current goal using a canonical proof of true, or the
> reflexivity tactic, or the contradiction tactic.

Comment: You could also do it with "exact true.intro" (since "true.intro" is a term of type "true", and that's exactly what you need to produce in order to complete the proof).

Comment: @HansLundmark Thanks, I was wondering what the underlying axiom was called.